# Using a (Zustand) function mock with Jest results in "TypeError: create is not a function"

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest, zustand

I'm following the [Zustand wiki to implement testing](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/wiki/Testing), but the provided solution is not working for a basic test for app rendering. My project is built on top of the [Electron React Boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) boilerplate project.

Here's the full error. Jest is using node with `experimental-vm-modules` because I followed the [the Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) to support ESM modules.

```
$ cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest
(node:85003) ExperimentalWarning: VM Modules is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision: myproject
  The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
    * <rootDir>/package.json
    * <rootDir>/src/package.json

 FAIL  src/__tests__/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: create is not a function

      12 | }
      13 |
    > 14 | const useNotifs = create<NotifsState>(
         |                   ^
      15 |   // devtools(
      16 |   (set) => ({
      17 |     notifStore: notifsDefault.notifStore,

      at src/state/notifs.ts:14:19
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:387:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:408:7)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.882 s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

At the top of the `notifs.ts` file, Zustand is imported normally with `import create from 'zustand'`.

Jest config in `package.json`:

```
    ...
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/config/mocks/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "zustand": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/zustand.js",
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(zustand)/)",
      "<rootDir>/src/node_modules/"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src/node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "json"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src/node_modules"
    ],
    "extensionsToTreatAsEsm": [
      ".ts",
      ".tsx"
    ],

    ...
```

I have left the `./src/__mocks__/zustand.js` file exactly the same as from the Zustand wiki Testing page. I receive the same error whether or not I have `zustand` in the `transformIgnorePatterns`.

My Babel configuration includes `[require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'), { loose: true }],` in the plugins section, and `output.library.type` is `'commonjs2'`

My `tsconfig.json` has `compilerOptions.module` set to `"CommonJS"`, and the project's `package.json` `"type"` field is set to `"commonjs"`.

Dependency versions:

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "webpack": "^5.5.1",
    "zustand": "^3.5.5"
```

I don't know what else could be relevant, just let me know if anything else is needed. Any and all help appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

To do this you should use the actual store of your app

```
const initialStoreState = useStore.getState()
 
 beforeEach(() => {
    useStore.setState(initialStoreState, true)
  })

useStore.setState({ me: memberMockData, isAdmin: true })
```

The documentation seems off. So don't follow it.

Comment: I was importing the same store used in the app, the line:

`const useNotifs = create<NotifsState>(`

Is from the store file, the `create` function is from `zustand`.

Comment: Much simpler than the official docs. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Looks similar to the error I came across:

```
    TypeError: store.getState is not a function

   9 | export const create = <S>(createState: StateCreator<S>) => {
  10 |      const store = actualCreate(createState);
> 11 |      const initialState = store.getState();
     |                                 ^
  12 |      storeResetFns.add(() => store.setState(initialState, true));
  13 |      return store;
  14 | };
```

In my case, it was caused by not currying the `create` function like so:

```
               
const create = () => <S>(createState: StateCreator<S>) => {
  const store = actualCreate(createState);
  const initialState = store.getState();
  storeResetFns.add(() => store.setState(initialState, true));
  return store;
};
```

See this [issue](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/issues/905#issuecomment-1491873447).

Answer (score 0):

use jest 28.0.0-alpha.0 will simply resolve the issue.
I think the problem is `zustand` uses '.mjs' as the entry point.

Comment: Dont do this it destroyed my node and test files.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm no longer working on this project so I can't test this solution, and because of @BonAndreOpina 's comment I'm hesitant to accept this. I wish the best of luck on anyone still trying to use Zustand with Jest.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to zustand.ts in **mocks** folder in order to mock Zustand.

```
__mocks__/zustand.ts

import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import { create as actualCreate } from 'zustand'

// a variable to hold reset functions for all stores declared in the app
const storeResetFns = new Set();
// @ts-ignore
const extension = {
  subscribe: jest.fn(() => {
    return () => {};
  }),
  unsubscribe: jest.fn(),
  send: jest.fn(),
  init: jest.fn(),
  error: jest.fn(),
};
const extensionConnector = { connect: jest.fn(() => extension) };
(window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ = extensionConnector;

// when creating a store, we get its initial state, create a reset function and add it in the set
const create = (createState: any) => {
  const store = actualCreate<any>(createState);
  const initialState = store.getState();
  storeResetFns.add(() => store.setState(initialState, true));
  return store;
};

// Reset all stores after each test run
afterEach(() => {
  act(() => storeResetFns.forEach((resetFn: any) => resetFn()));
});

export { create };
```

---

Make sure you do named export and not default for custom create method.